# How to call a function in one controller to the other controller in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to call a function in another controller. when i call this gives me an error.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::defaultBuckets()

I dont know why it gives me this error. I don't know i am calling this function rightly in another controller. Here is my code. Please Help.

Here is my function i created in my BucketController:

```php
public function defaultBuckets()
{
    $buckets = Bucket::where('bucket_type', 'default')->get();
}
```

And here is my Profile controller function Where i call this function:

```php
public function show(User $user)
{
    $authUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();

    if (! $user->isBlocking($authUser) && ! $user->isBlockedBy($authUser)) {
        if($authUser->id == $user->id){

           $profile = $user->where('id', $user->id)->defaultBuckets()->with([
            'posts', 'likes', 'followers', 'following'])->first(); 
        } else{

        $profile = $user->where('id', $user->id)->with([
            'posts' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('post_type', 'public');
            },
            'buckets' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('bucket_type', 'public');
            },
            'likes' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('post_type', 'public');
            },
            'followers', 'following'])->first();
        }
    return response()->json(['profile'=> $profile], 200);
    }

    return response()->json(['message'=> 'Your are not able to open profile of this user'], 200);
}
```

Comment: You are calling the function on the `Builder` object returned by `$user->where('id', $user->id)`. you are not calling it on the Controller

Comment: So how i can do ?

Comment: What is it the function needs to do ? your function just fills a variable but does nothing with it

Comment: I want to show default buckets that i get from this function in profile thats why i call it @mi

Comment: You need to make an instance of your controller `$bucketController = new BucketController();` and then `$bucketController->defaultBuckets();`

Comment: That i can do in my profile controller or in Bucket controller ? @Mike

Comment: You can put this in your profile controller but with the code you have right now it wont do anything because the function is not returning anything

Answer (score 1):

I Think there is mistake. You said you have this function in your **BucketController**

```
public function defaultBuckets()
{
  $buckets = Bucket::where('bucket_type', 'default')->get();
}
```

and then you are firing the function from **user model** in your **ProfileController**

```
$profile = $user->where('id', $user->id)->defaultBuckets()->with([
        'posts', 'likes', 'followers', 'following'])->first();
```

That is the reason it says that there is no function named "defaultBuckets".

You have to put this function in your **User model** and everything will work fine.

Also don't forget to return the buckets as well like this:

**To return all buckets**

```
public function defaultBuckets()
{
  $buckets = Bucket::where('bucket_type', 'default')->get();
  return $buckets; // all buckets
}
```

**To return a user's buckets only**

```
public function defaultBuckets()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Bucket::class)->where('bucket_type', 'default');
}
```

Make sure to accept the relationship from user in **bucket model** like this:

```
public function user(){
 return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'bucket_id' , 'user_id');
}
```

You can replace column names (bucket_id,user_id) according to your database.

Let me know if this fixes your problem